# Latin's scansion : length of vowels

Tags: formatting, kerning

I am a total enthusiastic beginner in LaTeX and my work in latin studies requires some twisty signs to mark the length of the vowels.
I would love to find a way to have the length display on the same level. If you know a way to do so, please tell me.

Here is a minimal working example of what i'm able to do so far. It's ok, but not perfect : the length marks are not on the same 'level'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%custom command : shortcut for formating
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{{\bf #1}}
\title{Latin' s Scansion}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{h\={a}s} \g{\={i}n}\ro{t\={e}r} / \g{p\={e}s}\ro{t\={e}s} // \g{d\=  {u}}\ro{r\={o}} /// \g{C\u{a}}t\u{o} \gr{m\={i}}l\u{i}t\u{e} \gr{s\={i}c}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

I can do what i want easily with this tool and import in ms Word : 
http://www.lexilogos.com/clavier/latin.htm

But with LaTeX, it doesn't work...

Thanks
Evelyne

Comment: I guess it has been fixed since all this time, because I don't have issues with those commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Lowering the duration marks for `i`

The page ["lexilogos"](http://www.lexilogos.com/clavier/latin.htm) removes the dot of the `i`. This can be achieved by using `\i` instead of `i`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%custom command : shortcut for formating
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\bfseries \color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{h\={a}s} \g{\={\i}n}\ro{t\={e}r} / \g{p\={e}s}\ro{t\={e}s} //
\g{d\=  {u}}\ro{r\={o}} /// \g{C\u{a}}t\u{o} \gr{m\={\i}}l\u{\i}t\u{e} 
\gr{s\={\i}c}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The same can be achieved by redefining `\={i}` and `\u{i}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%custom command : shortcut for formating
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\bfseries \color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{i}{\=\i}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{i}{\u\i}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{h\={a}s} \g{\={i}n}\ro{t\={e}r} / \g{p\={e}s}\ro{t\={e}s} //
\g{d\=  {u}}\ro{r\={o}} /// \g{C\u{a}}t\u{o} \gr{m\={i}}l\u{i}t\u{e}
\gr{s\={i}c}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Raising the duration marks to the same level

The duration marks for the other vowels can also be raised. The definitions are a little more complicate, because the position of the duration mark is measured, compared with the case `i` and raised to the same height.

Also the example shows, how to get rid of bold for the duration marks to get a more uniform appearance of the duration marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%custom command : shortcut for formating
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\bfseries \color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}

\newcommand*{\LongShortAux}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\mdseries #1{}}%
    \sbox2{\mdseries #1{j}}% j is used instead of i to prevent endless loop
    \ooalign{%
      \hidewidth\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax}{\mdseries#1{}}\hidewidth\cr
      \hfill#2\hfill
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{a}{\LongShortAux{\=}{a}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{e}{\LongShortAux{\=}{e}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{i}{\LongShortAux{\=}{i}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{o}{\LongShortAux{\=}{o}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{OT1}{u}{\LongShortAux{\=}{u}}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{a}{\LongShortAux{\u}{a}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{e}{\LongShortAux{\u}{e}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{i}{\LongShortAux{\u}{i}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{o}{\LongShortAux{\u}{o}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{OT1}{u}{\LongShortAux{\u}{u}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{h\={a}s} \g{\={i}n}\ro{t\={e}r} / \g{p\={e}s}\ro{t\={e}s} //
\g{d\=  {u}}\ro{r\={o}} /// \g{C\u{a}}t\u{o} \gr{m\={i}}l\u{i}t\u{e}
\gr{s\={i}c}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Remarks

- `\bfseries` is preferred over `\bf` in LaTeX2e. The old font commands have problems
  if they are mixed (e.g. `\it\bf`: bold wins -- `\itshape\bfseries`: both bold and italics).
- If another encoding is used (e.g. `T1`), then the `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand` lines need to be changed accordingly (e.g. `OT1` to `T1`).

### Combined solution with raised duration marks

This example combines:

- The redefined accented characters with raised duration marks.
- Unicode input ([egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123188/16967)).
- Better support for copy and pages (package `accsupp`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{stringenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

%custom command : shortcut for formating
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\bfseries \color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}

\newcommand*{\LongShortAux}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \StringEncodingConvert{\x}{\detokenize{#3}}{utf8}{utf16be}%
    \BeginAccSupp{%
      unicode,%
      method=plain,%
      ActualText=\x
    }%
      \sbox0{\mdseries #1{}}%
      \sbox2{\mdseries #1{j}}%
      \ooalign{%
        \hidewidth\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax}{\mdseries#1{}}\hidewidth
        \cr
        \hfill#2\hfill
      }%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DeclareLatinDuration}[3]{%
  \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{#1}{\f@encoding}{#2}{%
    \LongShortAux{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
  \@ifundefined{u8:\detokenize{#3}}{%
    \newunicodechar{#3}{#1{#2}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareLatinDuration{\=}{a}{ā}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\=}{e}{ē}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\=}{i}{ī}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\=}{o}{ō}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\=}{u}{ū}

\DeclareLatinDuration{\u}{a}{ă}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\u}{e}{ĕ}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\u}{i}{ĭ}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\u}{o}{ŏ}
\DeclareLatinDuration{\u}{u}{ŭ}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{hās} \g{īn}\ro{tēr} / \g{pēs}\ro{tēs} //
\g{dū}\ro{rō} /// \g{Că}tŏ \gr{mī}lĭtĕ
\gr{sīc}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Great solutions ! I have to decide which one is the best way. The solution with the newunicodechar, mentionned by egreg is also good way.

Comment: @Evelyne: egreg's solution uses the variant without dot above the `i` and deals with a more elegant input method (as Unicode char directly, if your keyboard allows to input them easily). My solution more deals with variants of the accents and how they can be defined. Thus you can even combine both methods, `\newunicodechar` with redefined accents.

Comment: Raising the duration marks to the same level and keeping the dot above the i really looks great from a latinist point of view. Thanks again for your time and very precise answers.

Comment: @Evelyne: I have added a combined solution with better support for copy and paste for PDF viewer that support the ActualText feature.

Answer (score 12):

The `newunicodechar` was written with this application in mind: directly typing characters with "strange" accents that are not covered by the standard `utf8` option to `inputenc`, in particular vowel length for Latin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\newunicodechar{ă}{\u{a}} % not needed (already defined by the utf8 option)
\newunicodechar{ĕ}{\u{e}}
\newunicodechar{ĭ}{\u{\i}}
\newunicodechar{ŏ}{\u{o}}
\newunicodechar{ŭ}{\u{u}}
\newunicodechar{ā}{\={a}}
\newunicodechar{ē}{\={e}}
\newunicodechar{ī}{\={\i}}
\newunicodechar{ō}{\={o}}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\={u}}

%custom command: shortcut for formatting
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\ro}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Latin's Scansion}
\author{Evelyne}
\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{rlll}
734 & \ro{hās} \g{īn}\ro{tēr} / \g{pēs}\ro{tēs} // \g{dū}\ro{rō} /// 
\g{Că}tŏ \gr{mī}lĭtĕ \gr{sīc}cum  &   SSSD  & hhhh \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution of course would be to use XeTeX instead, with an appropriate UTF-8 encoded font, say the [GNU Free family](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/), so the characters canbe input "as is" (e.g. Ă ḥ).